# Работа с графикой Сocos2D (Координатная система)

Tags: ios, cocos2d

Писать под iOS начал недавно. Сейчас просто разбираюсь в коде. Возникли непонятки, просьба помочь разобраться. Возьмем допустим эту статью: [RPG Style Game for the iPhone](http://www.iphonegametutorials.com/2011/05/04/cocos2d-game-tutorial-%E2%80%93-rpg-style-game-for-the-iphone-%E2%80%93-part-1-menus/). Вот что меня напрягло (разбираю кусок кода). Это я так понимаю

```
CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"menu_background.png"];
```

объявление и чтение спрайта из файла. А вот что меня напрягало, тут как я вижу мы его размещаем

```
background.position = ccp(winSize.width/2, winSize.height/2);
```

Получается, что мы размещаем его не в известных координатах а относительно размера экрана? (Делим высоту и ширину на 2, зн.находим центр.) А как же тогда быть в играх? Тоже все рассчитывать относительно? Допустим, в андроиде, я когда писал игры, использовал статичную координатную систему (480х800) и расставлял объекты относительно ее. Кто занимается играм на кокосе, что можете сказать насчет размещения элементов? Может я что-то не так понял?

**Добавлено.**

Define, извини не смог почему-то откомментировать. Так я и делаю на кокосе2Д, как там сделать кросплатформенно то? Разрешений экрана всего 3, вместе с IPad.
Я пока это вижу примерно так:

```
if(IPhone4Screen)
    CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"menu_background_ip4.png"];
    background.position = ccp(10, 20);
if(IPhone3Screen)
    CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"menu_background_ip3.png"];
    background.position = ccp(5, 10);
if(IPadScreen)
    CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"menu_background_ipad.png"];
    background.position = ccp(20, 30);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А я вот что нашел: [how does cocos2d-x support multi-resolution](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/How_does_cocos2d-x_support_multi-resolution).

> For example:
>
> The iphone4's dimension of screen is 320x480 points, but the screen's physical pixels is 640x960.
>
> Without retina display, the view scale one points to four pixels for display, full screen displayed picture need a image with size 320x480.
>
> But with retina display, full screen displayed picture whose name has the suffix "-hd" in cocos2d-x project need a image with size 640x960.

Я так понял, мы работаем в координатной системе 320х480, просто делаем картинки на 2 разрешения: те что с префиксом hd будут под ретиной на 640х960. Верно или нет?

Comment: Все верно, для ретины просто используется постфикс -hd (в кокосе), и @2x в простых нативных приложениях.

Comment: Ну с ретиной я понял так: расставляю все элементы в координатной системе 320х480. И просто делаю картинки в 2 раза больше оригинальных и сохраняю с постфиксом hd. А как с айпадом быть? С его разрешением экрана как поступить?
Кстати в нативных приложениях HD файл будет иметь имя вида filename@2x.jpg?

Comment: В нативных да.

Answer (score 0):

Размещается все естесственно по пикселям.
Мне кажется что winSize - это переменная типа CGPoint,  которая просто хранит размеры экрана.

Comment: Так смотрите, какой размер у него? На сколько я помню, у айфони 3 и 4 разные разрешения экрана. И как мне тогда  писать. 
Допустим в моем двиге на андре что я писал, там единая статичная координатная система, и если разрешение больше, расположение элементов остается тем-же только просто это все растягивалось на более большой экран (планшет например), также на маленьких экранах.

Comment: Делай для большего разрешения экрана(или для меньшего), и если необходимо запустить на другом разрешении масштабируй размер элементов, и их расположение. Может только тормозить начать.

Comment: Я тут подумал. Может проще определять какое разрешение экрана и иметь 2 проверки для расположения элементов?

Comment: Только не 2, а бесконечное количество. Простое масштабирование через коэффициенты. Я бы так делал.

Comment: Например? В андр играх я все точно по каждой координате рассчитывал.
Тут то разрешений два всего 640 x 960 и 320 х 480.

Comment: А iPad?
Вообще ясно что тут два пути:
1)делать отдельное приложение для каждого устройства
2)одно приложения для всех (со всеми от этого недостатками)

А если делать на кокос2д-х то можно делать кроссплатформенно, и соответственно разрешений экрана будет еще больше.

Comment: cocos2d-x.org
Другой вопрос нужна ли кроссплатформенность. И там бывают глюки.

Comment: Ну нужна поддержка 3,4 айфонов и айпада. Под андроид я вроде на своем движке и нормально пишу. И как бы сайт вроде этот знаю.

Comment: "Так я и делаю на кокосе2Д, как там сделать кросплатформенно то? "
Вот на что я отвечал. Я имел кроссплатформенность в понимании андройд, айос, винда, вфон(интересно зачем это?)
Если делать под  разные разрешения экрана, зачем делать выборку, если можно просто умножать на коэффициенты:
1024 768 - айпад, тогда:
y; size=1 - пиксельная верстка для айпад;
640/768*y size=640/768 -- айфон 4

Для длинны x коэффициенты те же что и для ширины(ввиду неодинаковости соотношений сторон)

Comment: Что-то я не догнал. Про коэфициенты

Answer (score 0):

Там должна быть строчка `CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];`
она отвечает за размеры экрана (сама их определяет в зависимости от девайса)...

Ты можешь изменить anchorPoint например: `background.anchorPoint = ccp(0, 0)`.
В этом случае ты располагаешь `background.position = ccp(0, 0);`